# System.InvalidOperationException: 'AddEntityFrameworkStores can only be called with a role that derives from IdentityRole<TKey>.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am attempting to register Identity with a custom class that inherits from **IdentityUser**, however, when I try, I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'AddEntityFrameworkStores can only
> be called with a role that derives from IdentityRole.'

I have tried a custom class that inherits from IdentityUserRole with no success.

Here is my relevant code:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityUserRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole
{

    public string MyRole { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Please share code for `ApplicationUser` and `ApplicationUserRole`.

Comment: The question has been edited, and the requested code has been provided.

Comment: What ASP.NET Core version are you using? Can you please post a [mre] somewhere?

Comment: I am using ASP.NET 7.0.

Comment: `ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole` does not even compile for me with ASP.NET Core 7.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I just made a fresh project, and tested it, and had no issues.

Comment: You should not be sorry, you should provide a working [mre] =) As far as I can see there is no non-generic `IdentityUserRole`, only [generic one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityuserrole-1?view=aspnetcore-7.0)